# How to click or trigger a hidden input file on Iphone (Embjer.js development)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

If I press a button, a hidden input file can be triggered:

HTML:

```
<button {{action 'addImage'}}>Click Me!</button>
<input id="addAttach" type="file" accept="application/*, image/*" style="display:none" />
```

JS (Ember.js):

```
actions:{
        addImage: function(){                                       
            Em.$('#addAttach').val('').click();
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work in Chrome on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try it the old fashioned way, I don't believe jQuery is even required:

```html
<button id="push" onclick="document.getElementById('add').click()">Click Me!</button>
<input id="add" type="file" style="display:none">
```